# Which books go into detail about Java Reference types?

Tags: java

Any book or article talking about the java references 
(strong, soft, weak,Phantom references)? How to use them (scenarios)?

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding Java (Strong, Weak, Soft and Phantom) References](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html). Moreover, technically the best core java book, I found is, Khalid Mughals' certification book, [A Programmer's Guide to Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321556054). It is dated, indeed.

Comment: Have you read "The Java Programming Language"? Its written by the creators of java.

Comment: @monksy: Nope. This sounds like a reference manual, and of course, must be having these things in there. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

[The Java Programming Language: Fourth Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349806) has a few pages about them. It is a very good reference, that goes into detail on how the garbage collection is performed, and how references are involved.